# VBA Excel SendKeys Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have some result data in sheet Extract that I need to activate cell by cell and press enter. It's alright for 10 cells but I have over 40 000. So i wrote some macro

```
   Sub Refresh()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Extract").Range("Q" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 2 To lastrow
            Sheets("Extract").Activate
            Sheets("Extract").Range("Q" & j).Select
            Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
            Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
            DoEvents
        Next j
End Sub
```

And it's not working. I'm gettin 1004 error Application-defined or Object-defined error.

What i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks for help

EDIT: 
Solution was simple. I did not activate Sheet Extract. 
I have add new line into code and everything works fine.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: What line are you receiving the error on?

Comment: Do you want (or have to) keep the same procedure? Can we remove the enter altogether and just have it loop through your events? Why is it necessary to press enter for the events to work?

Comment: What I read here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/697548-help-sendkeys-only-first-sendkey-command-works.html is that application.sendkeys can be helped by adding a slight delay when they are used one after the other. Maybe you could give it a try? Without context it is hard to give more help!

Comment: It will be enough if to selected cell will be send F2 and move to next cell in column Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub Refresh()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Worksheets("Extract").Activate
    lastrow = Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 2 To lastrow
        Range("Q" & j).Select
        Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
        Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
        DoEvents
    Next j
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

This version will remove the "chatter:**

```
Sub Refresh()
    Dim sOLD As Worksheet
    Set sOLD = ActiveSheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim lastrow As Long
        Worksheets("Extract").Activate
        lastrow = Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 2 To lastrow
            Range("Q" & j).Select
            Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
            Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
            DoEvents
        Next j
        sOLD.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you :)
Yeah this works fine. Only quick question. When I run macro all changes are visible to me (I see extract sheet and all actions which happen over there). How to set this macro to run more invisible ? I dont want to see what happen in Extract sheet.

Comment: It is strange but it works only for first 40 rows. Rest in range are DELETED.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looping through using `j` but in your code, referencing the cell in row `i`.

```
For j = 2 To lastrow
    Sheets("Extract").Range("Q" & i).Select
```

They need to be changed to match, ie change `i` to `j`.

Comment: Yeah rookie error but still:

Select method of Range class failed

Comment: Do you have the "Extract" sheet active?  If not, you'd either have to activate it or use the `Application.GoTo` command.

Comment: If you comment out the events after the range, does it still send a Range error? If not, what makes it send the error?

Answer (score 0):

The day has come when I decided to use Macro provided by Gary's Student (till now I was using my method). So i run macro again and I was suprised but macro worsk only for first 39 rows.

When I put on comment this line

```
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

It works fine but i see how macro is running row by row (I don't want to see that)

What can cause of problem ?